# Nested Scroll View is scrolling only till collapsing toolbar is collapsed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-nestedscrollview

Contents of Scroll Views are scrolling only till the Collapsing toolbar is collapsed. If contents of scroll view are huge,then some views are not getting inside the screen.
What to be done to fix this?
My Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingappbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="385dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingtool"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/collapsingappbar"
        android:layout_gravity="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movietitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/name"
                android:textColor="@color/detailstextcolor"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/moviename"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/detailstextcolor"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movieoverviews"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/overview"
                android:textColor="@color/detailstextcolor"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movieoverview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/detailstextcolor"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/moviedate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/date"
                android:textColor="@color/detailstextcolor"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movierelease"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/detailstextcolor"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movievotes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/votes"
                android:textColor="@color/detailstextcolor"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movievote"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/detailstextcolor"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movieratings"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/rating"
                android:textColor="@color/detailstextcolor"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movierating"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/detailstextcolor"
                android:textSize="14sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reviews"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/review" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/video" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fav"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/favs" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: set margin if a part of element not in screen